# Django - filter ForeignKey values in model's admin view

Tags: python, django

I've got two Django classes `Contact` and `Group`, where `Group` has two fields: `contact` and `contact_primary` linked to `Contact`. Like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)
    contact_primary = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

In the admin interface I can select a number of Contacts for the `contacts` field and then I want see only these selected contacts in the `contact_primary` dropdown. As it is now I can choose from all Contacts, whether they're selected in the ManyToMany field or not.

How can I restrict the Contacts displayed for `contact_primary` only to those selected in `contact`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jQuery/JavaScript.
just simply run a JavaScript/jQuery which we will make sure that contacts in  `contact_primary` is only those are selected in ManyToMany Field.

## steps

Field name of ManytoManyField  == contacts_id
Field name of contact_primary  == contact_primary_id
Now run a jQuery which will write selected contacts into contact_primary_id field at onblur/onselect event on ManytoMany field.

Comment: Thanks but I'd prefer to do it in Django as I'm not very keen to mess with the Admin interface with jQuery. I'm sure there must be a pure-Django way to do that.

Comment: Yes there is you can manage this using ajax .you need to send ajax request to your server